# Angular 11: Trigger 'activate' event of a <router-outlet> element in a Jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-router, angular11

I'm trying to write a test that is attempting to trigger the `activate` event of a `<router-outlet>` element. Here's my setup:

App routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'path/for/component/:id',
  component: MyComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MySubComponent, outlet: 'outletname' }
  ]
}];
```

MyComponent HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tab 1</ng-template>
    <router-outlet name="outletname" (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    <!-- more content here -->
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

MyComponent TS:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  onActivate(obj: any): void { /* do the things */ }
}
```

MyComponent Spec:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeAll(() => {
    activatedRoute = new ActivatedRoute();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    /* 
     * set activatedRoute properties such as URL and component to try
     * to get the onActivate() callback to fire on component render
     */
  });

  it('should test results of onActivate event', async () => {
    /*
     * 1. setup and construct the component
     * 2. test result of onActivate() callback
     */
  });
});
```

For anyone who's curious, all that's really happening in the full component implementation is that the `activate` callback just notifies `MyComponent` as to which tab is currently being displayed so that I can throw up a dialog box should the user navigate to the other tab when necessary.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to properly mock up the `ActivatedRoute` object to get the  `activate` event to fire when `MyComponent` is constructed in my test. As I understand it, and I could be totally wrong here, the `<router-outlet>` should fire when the current route matches the `path` in my list of routes. Ideally, I'd like to fire the `activate` callback without having to explicitly call it in my test, i.e. I do not want to have to say `component.onActivate(eventObj)` in my test. I expect the `<router-outlet>` to render as part of the component construction as long as `ActivatedRoute` has the proper information. So, the question is: how much of `ActivatedRoute` must be specified in the `beforeEach()` function in order to get the `<router-outlet>` to render properly? Is this even possible? Am I completely on the wrong track? Am I overthinking this?

I'd like to eventually use an `ActivatedRoute` mock class instead of the actual class to reduce the amount of overhead and only provide the minimum necessary functionality to facilitate further tests, but I have to get this one to work first before I can properly abstract out a utility class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!